# Test Class on a trigger which restricts the user to enter more than 100%

Tags: unit-test

I have a custom object: Team Member. It is looking up to another custom object Vendor_Contract (Vendor Contract to Team Member is 1 to many relationship). My trigger accurately restricts users to create mulitple Team Members with total allocations exceeding above 100 % for a particular Vendor Contract. For example Vendor 1 has 3 Team Members. The allocation sum of these 3 team members cant exceed 100%.
I have written the following Test class which is unable to provide coverage. Not sure how to handle this. Any help will be definitely helpful.

```
 @isTest static void TestCreateNewLabContAllocMoreThan100(){
    List<Team_Member__c> tms= New List<Team_Member__c>();

    Vendor_Contract__c ven= New Vendor_Contract__c(Name='Test Vendor');
    Insert ven;

    Insert team;
    for(Integer i=0; i<200; i++){
        Team_Member__c tm= New Team_Member__c(Vendor_Contract__c=ven.id, Allocation_to_Team__c=1);
        tms.add(tm);
    }
     
    String message;
    Test.startTest();
    try{
        insert tms;
    }catch(Exception e){
        message = e.getMessage();
    }
    Test.stopTest();   
    List<Vendor_Contract__c> venCont = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Allocation_to_Team__c FROM Team_Members__r) FROM Vendor_Contract__c WHERE Id =:ven.Id];
    for(Team_Member__c tm:venCont.Team_Members__r){
        system.assertEquals(tm.Allocation_to_Team__c, 1);            
    }
    
}
```

Comment: delete `try-catch` block that is covering your `insert tms;` and you will see actual exception, that is preventing you to cover trigger logic.

Comment: Hi Oleksandr... Thanks for your help. But, it's still the same. My test coverage is unchanged. What worries me is how can my test allow to create more than 100 team members when I have restricted the same in the trigger.